# rails_env - where is code executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I run a rails console like this

```
Rails_env=uat
```

And run some code

```
user = User.find(1)
user.do something
```

Where the code executed, is it the code on the server, or my local code, which could be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its executed on the machine where the shell is running.

What the `RAILS_ENV` env var does is tell rails which config files to load. So if you use `RAILS_ENV = production` it will load `/config/environments/production.rb` and it will also use the `production` section in your `database.yml`.

It does not magically open a SSH connection and execute on your production server. Just think about it, how would that work? Rails has no idea where the production server lives and how to open a connection.

### Warning!

However since it uses the `production` section in your `database.yml` it can change your production database if you are foolish enough to actually write the production server details in the file (Don't be a tool, use the DATABASE_URL env var).

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html